# Alamofire shows warning when setting deployment target to 9.0

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, alamofire

I am trying to using Alamofire in my project , i have downloaded the latest file from Github and added the framework to my project. Then i came to Read that we need to set the Deployment target of Alamofire to same as our project deployment Target. My project Deployment target is **9.0** and when i set the Deployment Target of Alamofire to **9.0** it throws a warning

> Unnecessary check for 'iOSApplicationExtension'; minimum deployment
>   target ensures guard will always be true

how to avoid this warning ?

Comment: Could you file a bug on the Alamofire project so we could get it fixed properly?

Comment: @cnoon Okay i will report a new issue.

Comment: For reference, this is the link of the issue https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/871